# Getting template for a s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

It is possible to get a template (yml) for a s3 bucket created using the web console?.
I just want to see how was configured a particular s3, but see it in a template form.

Comment: What type of configuration information are you seeking? Are you wanting to replicate the configuration for another bucket?

Comment: Yes, i want to see how the configuration template looks, and then replicate directly on cloudformation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible with the new AWS tool called CloudFormer. The tool is still in beta though.

> CloudFormer is a template creation beta tool that creates an AWS CloudFormation template from existing AWS resources in your account. You select any supported AWS resources that are running in your account, and CloudFormer creates a template in an Amazon S3 bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Comment: I doubt that CloudFormer will include much "configuration" information about the bucket. But, give it a try!

Comment: Thanks!!, i'll give a try.